# Bind string to checkbox value in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I've been browsing for a few hours, found similar examples, however, couldn't make it to work.

In my JSON file I've got property "accessRight" which could be "full", "read" or "none"
Then in HTML I've got 3 checkboxes for "full" "read" and "none".
If "accessRight" is set to "read", I want this checkbox to be checked and got this code to do it.

```
                <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="accessRight" data-ng-true-value="read">
```

However the checkbox get checked even if "accessRight" isn't set to "read", how could I fix it?

Also tried this but still no luck.

```
                <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="accessRight" data-ng-true-value="read">
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="accessRight" data-ng-true-value="'read'">
```

Surrrounding read with single quotes, see:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Answer (score 1):

try to use:

```
checked="accessRight == 'read'"
```

if your model is accressRight you can also try

```
data-ng-true-value="accessRight.read == ture"
```

or

```
data-ng-true-value="accessRight == 'read'"
```

it really depend on your model

Answer (score -1):

I think you mistake value of data-ng-true-value.
The correct like this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="accessRight" data-ng-true-value="'read'">
```